# RETROFIT 2.0 unbale to acess api response data contains any list

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Hi guys i have struck with one problem while i am trying to access one api services  it is all working fine. But my issue iin processing the response .

I am using retrofit 2.0

Below is my json response for my api

```
    {
  "status": 200,
  "success": "true",
  "data": [
    {
      "works_node": [
        {
          "works_items": [
            {
              "work_id": "number",

              "preference": "number",
              "Task_created_time": "datetime yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "questions_node": [
        {
          "questions_items": [
            {
              "q_id": "number",
              "work_id": "number",
              "question_text": "string",
              "preference": "number" 
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "answers_node": [
        {
          "answers_items": [
            {
              "a_id": "number",
              "q_id": "number",
              "answer_text": "string",
              "prefernce": "number",
              "point": "number",
              "is_suggest": "number",
              "work_id": "number"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "answer_suggestions_node": [
        {
          "answer_suggestions_items": [
            {
              "a_id": "number",
              "q_id": "number",
              "answer_suggestion_text": "string",
              "point": "number",
              "work_id": "number"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the api calling code

```
public  void getWorkTaskConfig(){
    ApiInterface apiService =  ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    String DeviceImei=uf.getIMEI();
    int userId=db.getUserId();

    Call<WorkTaskConfig> call = apiService.getWorkTaskConfig
            (new BasicData(new UserInfo(userId),new DeviceInfo(DeviceImei)));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<WorkTaskConfig>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<WorkTaskConfig> call, Response<WorkTaskConfig> response) {
            try {
                int apiStatus= response.body().getStatus();
                Boolean apiSuccess=response.body().getSuccess();
                if (apiStatus == Constants.RESULT_CODE_OK &&
                        apiSuccess.equals(Constants.RESULT_SUCCESS_OK)) {     //data received successfully
                    List<Datum> apiAllWorkTaskConfigData=response.body().getData();
                    List<WorksNode> apiAllWorksNodeData=response.body().getData().getWorksNode();    // im facing 
                    //the problem here ie i am not able to access the getWorksNode() function 
                    //in Datum.java class. 
                }else{                  //while retrieving data something went wrong.  
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        } 
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<WorkTaskConfig> call, Throwable t) {   }
    }); 
}
```

**WorkTaskConfig.java**

```
public class WorkTaskConfig {
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Integer status;

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = null;

    public Integer getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Integer status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**Datum.java**

```
public class Datum {

    @SerializedName("works_node")
    @Expose
    private List<WorksNode> worksNode = null;

    public List<WorksNode> getWorksNode() {
        return worksNode;
    }

    public void setWorksNode(List<WorksNode> worksNode) {
        this.worksNode = worksNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? What's the issue?

Comment: @azizbekian i am not able to write this line `ist<WorksNode> apiAllWorksNodeData=response.body().getData().getWorksNode();` if write it produces the error

Comment: Edit with the log cat of the error

Comment: @azizbekian if writes it displays `cannot ressolve the method getWorksNode()`

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier `cannot ressolve the method getWorksNode()` this is the error

Comment: `getData()` is a list you to do `getData().get(position).getWorksNode()`

Comment: ...getData() returns a List. To access an element of it you could e.g. call response.body().getData().get(0).getWorksNode();

Comment: how can i introduce this`get(position).` in the api response handling ?

Comment: @DamianJäger this is also producing the error `incompatiable types`

Comment: Edit with the all error

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier it is not working in this case ?

Comment: Which case, you have a new error right ?

Comment: i am not able introduce `.get(position).`

Comment: @azizbekian please see the update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

1. Edit Json `structure`
2. Edit POJO class(`Datum`)

**Edit Json Structure**

> `data` is an object, not array.

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "success": "true",
    "data": {
        "works_node": [{
            "works_items": [{
                "work_id": "number",
                "preference": "number",
                "Task_created_time": "datetime yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s"
            }]
        }],
        "questions_node": [{
            "questions_items": [{
                "q_id": "number",
                "work_id": "number",
                "question_text": "string",
                "preference": "number"
            }]
        }],
        "answers_node": [{
            "answers_items": [{
                "a_id": "number",
                "q_id": "number",
                "answer_text": "string",
                "prefernce": "number",
                "point": "number",
                "is_suggest": "number",
                "work_id": "number"
            }]
        }],
        "answer_suggestions_node": [{
            "answer_suggestions_items": [{
                "a_id": "number",
                "q_id": "number",
                "answer_suggestion_text": "string",
                "point": "number",
                "work_id": "number"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

**Edit POJO class**

> go to link below and generate the `pojo class` again.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

**And Try this.**

```
WorkTaskConfig taskConfig = reponse.body();

List<WorksNode> worksNode = taskConfig.getData().getWorksNode();
List<QuestionsNode> questionsNode = taskConfig.getData().getQuestionsNode();
List<AnswersNode> answersNode = taskConfig.getData().getAnswersNode();
List<AnswerSuggestionsNode> answerSuggestionsNode = taskConfig.getData().getAnswerSuggestionsNode();
```

Comment: Please the above json structure.

Comment: each node in "data": will contains mutiple nodes

Comment: @PranavMS umm. I think you incorrect json structure why data(Datum) is List??

Comment: then what type should i declare for that

Comment: His anwser works, it will be juste the same process for the other list. You just need to add them in your `class Datum`.

Comment: i created the classes from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ here only by pasting my json here.

Comment: @EthanChoi  `JSONObject apiAllWorkTaskConfigData=response.body().getData();
                       //List<String> apiAllWorksNodeData=response.body().getData().getWorksNode();
                        JSONObject apiAllworks_node=  apiAllWorkTaskConfigData.getJSONObject("works_node");` is this right way ?

Comment: @EthanChoi it means i should rewrite all the pojo class again ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136231/discussion-between-pranav-ms-and-ethan-choi).

Comment: @EthanChoi hello can you please help me here .. When i try to call the api , I am getting error

Answer (score -1):

Replace all `WorkTaskConfig`  to `JsonElement` if you are facing some problem .
and Parse manually with Gson like..

`String apiAllWorkTaskConfigData = response.body().getData();
WorkTaskConfig mWorkTaskConfig = new Gson.fromJson(apiAllworkTaskConfigData,WorkTaskConfig.class);`

Comment: what the error u got..?      Or  maybe u need to confirm your response that are comes when you call api is same as your response class

Comment: all the files got affected.. my `response.body().getData();` is list array ie it is multi dimensional array ..

Comment: you need to change in all case of `WorkTaskConfig` to `JsonElement` after this change you will get complete response in JsonElement this you can use like String response ...

Comment: Because if he change `WorkTaskConfig` he need to change it in his interface too. But when GSON doesn't parse normally, he return a specfic error.